# How to solve this error on BigQuery- INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

While trying to join departments table with employees tables within employee_data dataset in BigQuery, I am getting this error -**Table "departments" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).**
I tried including dataset name to each

```
SELECT
employees.name As Emp_Name,
employees.role As Emp_Role,
departments.name AS Dept_Name
FROM `decoded-cove-403402.employee_data.departments` 
INNER JOIN
departments ON
employees.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

[image]